# PrimeFaces: Inputs doesn't work (not receive input values ​or focus)

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Using JSF and PrimeFaces, I was making a screen, but for some reason any situations in which a keyboard input is needed, they don't work.

It is not possible to focus with the mouse, just pressing TAB at some point it accesses the Input field, however, it is still impossible to type any value in it.

- Inputs do not receive Focus
- Input fields cannot be typed/updated it is as if the field is locked
- No existing Readonly parameter
- Using Templates
- Another Page that has Inputs work correctly

Example of the situation:
[ProblemExample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5O4y.gif)

**Template in .xhtml**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      lang="en">

    <h:head>
        <f:facet name="first">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0"/>
            <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
        </f:facet>
        <title><ui:insert name="title">PrimeFaces Ecuador</ui:insert></title>
        <h:outputScript name="js/nanoscroller.js" library="ecuador-layout" />
        <h:outputScript name="js/layout.js" library="ecuador-layout" />
        <ui:insert name="head"/>
    </h:head>

    <h:body>
        <div class="layout-wrapper #{guestPreferences.menuMode}">
            <ui:include src="./ddoTopbar.xhtml"></ui:include>

            <div class="layout-main">
                <div class="route-bar">
                    <div class="route-bar-breadcrumb">
                        <i class="fa fa-home"></i> 
                        <span>/ </span>
                        <ui:insert name="viewname" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                <div class="layout-content" style="min-height:300px">
                    <ui:insert name="content"></ui:insert>
                </div>

                <div class="route-bar">
                    <div class="route-bar-breadcrumb" style="float: right;">
                        <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-up"></i> 
                        <span>/ </span>
                        <ui:insert name="viewtopo" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <p:ajaxStatus styleClass="layout-ajax-loader">
                <f:facet name="start">
                    <i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin layout-ajax-loader-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </f:facet>

                <f:facet name="complete">
                    <h:outputText value="" />
                </f:facet>
            </p:ajaxStatus>
        </div>
       
        <h:outputStylesheet name="css/nanoscroller.css" library="ecuador-layout" />
        <h:outputStylesheet name="css/layout-#{guestPreferences.layout}.css" library="ecuador-layout" />
    </h:body>

</html>
```

**.xhtml of the page**

```html
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" 
    xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions" template="/WEB-INF/ddoTemplate.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="title">Title</ui:define>
    
    
    <ui:define name="head">
    
    </ui:define>
    
    <ui:define name="viewname">
        <li><p:link id="idHome" outcome="/dashboard.xhtml">Home</p:link></li>
    </ui:define>

    <ui:define name="content">
        <div class="layout-dashboard">
            <div class="ui-g">
              <h:form id="frmCadastroDiarioObra" class="ui-g-12 ui-md-12 ui-lg-12 ui-xl-12">
                    <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" />
                    <p:panel header="Central de atendimento"
                        styleClass="resolution-center"
                        rendered="#{diarioObrasMB.exibeDadosDiarioSelecionado}">
                        
                        <p:inputText placeholder="*Nome" value="#{diarioObrasMB.nome}"/>
                        
                        <p:inputText placeholder="*E-mail" value="#{diarioObrasMB.email}"/>

                        <p:selectOneMenu id="console" value="">
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="*Assunto" itemValue="" />
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Reportar problema" itemValue="Reportar problema" />
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Solicitar informação" itemValue="Solicitar informação" />
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Enviar elogio" itemValue="Enviar elogio" />
                        </p:selectOneMenu>

                        <p:inputTextarea rows="3" placeholder="*Mensagem" value="#{diarioObrasMB.mensagem}"
                            autoResize="false" />

                    </p:panel>              
                </h:form>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

Comment: In F12 console in your browser are you getting any JavaScript errors?

Comment: No, no error messages or warnings for this page or an attempt to use Inputs.

Comment: Do you try without the template? With browser console, you should see if there's an object with a higher z-index that covers the input fields, or the js called by the page.

Comment: I didn't try it without the Template, but I can't say if that would be it, as I have another identical template working correctly for another page, but I'll try anyway. About "higher z-index that covers the input fields" I made this conference and that's not the problem either. About the page's JS, it's structured the same as another page that's also working, I did both the same way, so I'm confused about what's causing this problem.

Comment: rebuild without the template didn't do it either.

Comment: There're too many missing things to reproduce your case(included file, css, js), can you post a fully reproducible example? I had a similar problem, only on chrome, using a custom template, with the style of a disabled selectOneMenu(the hidden panel disabled the input text under it).

Comment: I'll be closing this topic, because for some unknown reason the problem was solved. Possible problems:
- Bugs with Eclipse;
- Incompatibility and some problem with Chrome;
- Clearing the Browser Cache may help to "solve" this problem;


What happened with me?!
I restarted the application to demonstrate an error, it was demonstrated, Chrome crashed, I restarted, I cleared the Cache and then from then on everything went back to working normally.